# Why does it seem my skeleton is working fine in Blender but it completely fails in UE4?

Tags: animation

[image]

I am very new to blender but after spending a few days I feel like I've finally given the mesh good weight painting. I can move around the joints and while there are a few flaws in it, it shouldn't nearly as bad as it is in UE4. Note that the left is a photo from a pose, not an animation, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Here is the file I'm using. In it is Buzz and also the model with the Mixamo animation I'm trying to use for Buzz. I couldn't find how to use that exact animation on Buzz, but I would really like to, because I could then determine if this is an issue with the animation or an issue between the programs.

It's one solid mesh, pretty sure I'm using default settings, except for turned off the leaf bones. The bones have the weight painting on very close to the bones, except for the chest because Buzz's chest isn't that flexible, but that shouldn't be affecting the legs which work perfectly fine. I think it's worth noting that I am also able to bend Buzz into poses in UE4, so it appears this issue only comes up when animating.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Note that the left is a photo from a pose" - which photo? There aren't any in this question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I've added them back in.